# Facebook Graph API - Months of Missing Page Posts from /posts

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.1

I've searched high and low for an answer to why this is happening with no luck.

When pulling and paginating results from a page's `/posts`, MONTHS of posts are missing. Things I have checked:

- **The user posting on the page has been ruled out**. Posts that do show and posts that are missing can be from the same user
- **Post types seem not to matter**. Posts that do show and those that are missing can be of the same post type
- **I have access to view the missing posts via my app** - by querying for any of the missing posts, my app can access the post data, insights, etc
- The missing posts are **published, and public**

The missing posts are only viewable when exporting from the "Export Data" option in the page admin section of the Facebook site.

My query:

```
$fb->get('/{PAGEID}/posts?fields=name,created_time,message,parent_id&since={SINCE}&until={UNTIL}&limit=100', '{ACCESS_TOKEN}');
```

Paginating through these results, for example, when querying results between `2017-10-01` and `2017-11-01`, returns 2 out of ~30 posts from Oct 27 (and not the first or last posts of that day), with dates later than Oct 27 showing most posts (only a handful missing) and dates before Oct 27 not showing at all.

Using Graph API `2.10`.

Any ideas as to why so many posts are missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1838195226492053/) in the Facebook API. I have the same issue. A staff member [commented](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1838195226492053/?comment_id=1857804467864462),

> I've been informed by the product team that they will not be fixing the existing endpoint since it is working by design, as in it accurately represents what is visible of the pages feed to a user on the UI.
>
> They are working on a new endpoint which will fetch all posts published by the page not subject to the limitations of feed. This is something we will be testing internally very soon.

The bug was reported on 22 September and the comment posted on 26 October. Another staff member [commented](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1432764036848970/?comment_id=1433966153395425) on a duplicate of the bug on 14 November,

> Unfortunately, we do not have an ETA on when the new endpoint will be ready. As a result, the bug was labeled closed to manage developer expectation that the fix won't be ready short-term.

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions on a possible workaround in the meantime?

Comment: Not really. Google's [cache](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ftheguardian%2F+%22november+3+at%22) or the [Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170722215734/http://facebook.com/theguardian) are both far from perfect unless all you want to do is look up individual posts.